# How is main() called? Call to main() inside __libc_start_main()

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, program-entry-point, disassembly, libc

I am trying to understand the call to `main()` inside `__libc_start_main()`. I know one of the parameters of `__libc_start_main()` is the address of `main()`. But, I am not able to figure out how is main() being called inside `__libc_start_main()` as there is no Opcode `CALL` or `JMP`. I see the following disassembly right before execution jumps to `main()`.

```
   0x7ffff7ded08b <__libc_start_main+203>:  lea    rax,[rsp+0x20]
   0x7ffff7ded090 <__libc_start_main+208>:  mov    QWORD PTR fs:0x300,rax
=> 0x7ffff7ded099 <__libc_start_main+217>:  mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x1c3e10]        # 0x7ffff7fb0eb0
```

I wrote a simple `"Hello, World!!"` in C. In the assembly above:

1. The execution jumps to `main()` right after instruction at address **`0x7ffff7ded099`**.
2. Why is the **`MOV` (to RAX)** instruction causing a jump to `main()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, of course those instructions are not the ones that cause the call to `main`. I am not sure how you are stepping through those instructions, but if you are using GDB, you should use `stepi` instead of `nexti`.

I don't know why this happens precisely (some strange GDB or x86 quirk?) so I only speak from personal experience, but when reverse-engineering ELF binaries, I occasionally find that the `nexti` command executes several instructions before breaking. In your case, it misses a few `mov`s before the actual `call rax` to call `main()`.

What you can do to remediate this is to either use `stepi`, or to dump more code and then explicitly tell GDB to set breakpoints:

```
(gdb) x/20i
    0x7ffff7ded08b <__libc_start_main+203>: lea    rax,[rsp+0x20]
    0x7ffff7ded090 <__libc_start_main+208>: mov    QWORD PTR fs:0x300,rax
 => 0x7ffff7ded099 <__libc_start_main+217>: mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x1c3e10]        # 0x7ffff7fb0eb0
    ... more lines ...
    ... find call rax ...
(gdb) b *0x7ffff7dedXXX <= replace this
(gdb) continue
```

Here's what `__libc_start_main()` on my system does to call `main()`:

```
21b6f:  48 8d 44 24 20          lea    rax,[rsp+0x20]               ; start preparing args
21b74:  64 48 89 04 25 00 03    mov    QWORD PTR fs:0x300,rax
21b7b:  00 00
21b7d:  48 8b 05 24 93 3c 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x3c9324] 
21b84:  48 8b 74 24 08          mov    rsi,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
21b89:  8b 7c 24 14             mov    edi,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x14]
21b8d:  48 8b 10                mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rax]
21b90:  48 8b 44 24 18          mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18]     ; get address of main
21b95:  ff d0                   call   rax                          ; actual call to main()
21b97:  89 c7                   mov    edi,eax
21b99:  e8 32 16 02 00          call   431d0 <exit@@GLIBC_2.2.5>    ; exit(result of main)
```

The first three instructions are the same that you show. At the moment of `call rax`, `rax` will contain the address of `main`. After calling `main`, the result is moved into `edi` (first argument) and `exit(result)` is called.

Looking at [glibc's source code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/csu/libc-start.c.html#308) for `__libc_start_main()`, we can see that this is exactly what happens:

```c
/* ... */

#ifdef HAVE_CLEANUP_JMP_BUF
  int not_first_call;
  not_first_call = setjmp ((struct __jmp_buf_tag *) unwind_buf.cancel_jmp_buf);
  if (__glibc_likely (! not_first_call))
    {
      /* ... a bunch of stuff ... */
      /* Run the program.  */
      result = main (argc, argv, __environ MAIN_AUXVEC_PARAM);
    }
  else
    {
      /* ... a bunch of stuff ... */
    }
#else
  /* Nothing fancy, just call the function.  */
  result = main (argc, argv, __environ MAIN_AUXVEC_PARAM);
#endif
  exit (result);
}
```

In my case I can see from the disassembly that `HAVE_CLEANUP_JMP_BUF` was defined when my glibc was compiled, so the actual call to `main()` is the one inside the `if`. I also suspect this is the case for your glibc.

Comment: Interesting...
I am not sure why I don't see "CALL RAX" instruction in my disassembly.

Comment: @Harry I've added instructions on how to make GDB show more lines.

Comment: Yea, I see the "CALL RAX" now which answers my question. It is weird GDB would skip few instructions when using "nexti"....

Comment: "I often find that the nexti command executes several instructions before breaking." -- this is pretty much impossible on `x86_64`, I have _never_ seen this happen (and I debug _all day long_). Something _else_ is happening.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I don't really know how to explain such behavior really... I know it's nonsensical, but this happened to me before... I probably shouldn't say "often" though, it's rare. It could be a bug of the [GDB plugin](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg) I'm using, IDK. I'm interested though, why do you say this is impossible on x86-64? Is this fully backed by hardware features or something?